creating forest plot for a multiple logistic regression
I have created a multiple logistic regression using finalfit package and I need to create forest plot for this model but it is very crowded so I want to remove the values of odds ratio and CI from the plot
TT1<-PCCS%>%
  or_plot(dep1,exp1) 

this is the code I used to creat the forestplot.
Is there is any code I can use to remove the numbers or even another code to make forest plot for logistic model?

You just need to stretch the plot window. There's no argument in or_plot  to remove the OR and 95% CI from the plot. But you can edit the function easily enough to do this.

There's no argument in the or_plot function to remove the OR and 95% CI from the plot. But you can edit the function easily enough to do this. But have you tried stretching the plot window?
An example from the help page of OR_plot
library(finalfit)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# OR plot
explanatory = c("age.factor", "sex.factor", "obstruct.factor", "perfor.factor")
dependent = "mort_5yr"


colon_s %>%
  or_plot(dependent, explanatory, table_text_size=4, title_text_size=14,
          plot_opts=list(xlab("OR, 95% CI"), theme(axis.title = element_text(size=12))))


Quite crowded, but if you stretch the plot window you can get something like this:

If you really don't want the OR or 95% CI in the plot, then just edit the function:
new_or_plot <- edit(or_plot)

Then add the following argument to the function, assigning it to FALSE:
add_OR = FALSE,

Then modify lines 83 - 93:
t1 = ggplot(df.out, aes(x = as.numeric(OR), y = fit_id)) + 
    annotate("text", x = column_space[1], y = df.out$fit_id, 
      label = df.out[, 2], hjust = 0, size = table_text_size) + 
    annotate("text", x = column_space[2], y = df.out$fit_id, 
      label = df.out[, 3], hjust = 1, size = table_text_size)

if(add_OR) t1 <- t1 + annotate("text", x = column_space[3], y = df.out$fit_id, 
      label = df.out[, 8], hjust = 1, size = table_text_size)

t1 <- t1 + theme_classic(14) + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "white"), 
    axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "white"), axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
    axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
    line = element_blank())

Save, and then run the following line:
colon_s %>%
  new_or_plot(dependent, explanatory, table_text_size=4, title_text_size=14,
              plot_opts=list(xlab("OR, 95% CI"), theme(axis.title = element_text(size=12))),
              OR_opts=FALSE)



thanks for your reply but I did not understand what do you mean modify lines 83 - 93:

After entering the function editor, scroll down to line 83 and replace the code on lines 83 to 93 with my modified version.
